# How do I make the system to ask for keyboard and mouse?

Tags: keyboard, imac, mouse

I have a Mac 21.5 from 2015 that I hadn't used for a while. A few weeks ago, I used it with a USB mouse and its original keyboard but didn't use it afterwards.

Today, when I turned it on, it didn't recognize the keyboard or the wireless mouse. It also didn't prompt for a mouse or keyboard as it usually does, leaving me with no control unless I plug in a USB keyboard and mouse.

I tried turning both the keyboard and mouse on and off, and restarting the computer. I also tried two different keyboard and mouse sets from other iMacs I have, but nothing worked.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

PS: sorry if this question exist, I did a search but couldn't find anything

Comment: Check your BT devices and pair the keyboard and mouse